# How to mock sequelize in commonjs with sinon?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, chai, sinon, stub

I tried to use the code below but it keeps on telling me

> Cannot stub non-existent property query

is there a way to stub sequelize query?

all I find on the net is the object base sequelize.

this is the code

```
const query = async () => {
    const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
    let db = {};
    let sequelize = new Sequelize({
        dialect: "mysql",
        database: "sample",
        username: "test",
        password: "test",
        host: "sample",
        operatorsAliases: 0,
        logging: false,
    
    });
    
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    let result = {};
    let _metadata = [];
    try {
        [result, _metadata] = await sequelize.query(query);
        result._metadata = _metadata;
    }finally{
        await sequelize.close();
    }
    return result;
}

module.exports = { query }
```

this is the test

```
const sinon = require("sinon");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("./db");

describe("Sequelize Unit Test", () => {
    context("Unit Test Start", () => {
        let sequelizeStub;
         beforeEach(async () => {
            sequelizeStub = sinon.stub(Sequelize, "query");
        });
        // Runs after each test case
        afterEach(async () => {
            sequelizeStub.restore();
        });

        it("returns object", async () => {
            sequelizeStub.return({ result: [], metadata: [] });
            let test = await db.query("test", mockSMcred );
            console.log(test);
        });

    }
}
```

for some reason I can't stub the query?
tried node modules, I don't see any querys

I can't use the model sequelize because i'm maintaining some old code.
I really have no idea how to do it anymore.

my only way is just using the query

Comment: Your code can't run, please fix the syntax and provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @slideshowp2  it will work now